# Single view IOS app with only an MKMapView crashes when not connected to xcode

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

When connected with Xcode it works perfect in Simulator, but when I disconnect it, the app exits immediately. If I delete the MapView everything is OK, so I think the problem is with the MapView. I inserted the MapView Outlet in the ViewController, and in Storyboard I added the ViewController class.

log:

`assertion failed: 19A583 17A844: libxpc.dylib + 83383`

`Service exited due to SIGABRT`

Comment: Xcode 11, ios 13

Comment: We need to see how you setup your mapView in order to help you. By the looks of it, I would say the issue might be with you not requesting location permission, ending up with (0, 0) coordinates, and doing some division by 0 which crashes the app.